# Help identifying MTB frame

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

Apologies making ANOTHER one of these threads...Anyhows:
Bought a bike third hand, frame has been stripped and painted. Trying to find make & model so I can get some offset bushings for the shock. I'm guessing this was either a custom build or a lot has been swapped out since, but just in case:

- Fork: Rockshox reba
- Shock: Fox Float RPL
- Brakes/Calipers: Avid ELIXIR 5
- Rear derailleur: Shimano XTR, 9 speed

One of the most identifiable things I could notice was the uneven chainstays.
Material is aluminium.
Serial (under BB) starts with "kcps00" if that helps at all.
Can take more pictures if needed.

[image: Bike]

[image: Chainstay closeup 2]

Thanks!

Comment: I think most of the components probably aren't the originals, even possibly the fork is changed. The derailleur hanger usually gives an idea of the brand, either stamped on it or by looking through the wheels mfg charts. Headset, seat collar, seat post also can give an indication of brand.

Comment: Looks a lot like a Jamis, but I can't really nail down a matching model, so I might be barking up the wrong tree. Other clues:
 + Note the cable routing underneath the top tube (somewhat unusual for this type of frame setup). 
 + Definitely spec'd as a hydro-disc-brake bike.
 + "KCP" is a bicycle distribution group in/around Greece.

Comment: At first I was thinking Transition Bottlerocket (shock mount looks right, linkage pretty close, used a chain guide like that....) but there is a pivot on the chainstay. Bottlerocket had it on the seat stay. Jamis Dakar also has shock mount and linkage like that, but again, pivot on the seatstay not the chainstay. So it would be a horst link / fsr variant?

Comment: Have you tried to look with google's searching engine for images?